# Post form with array fields parsed as null by Sparkjava

Tags: java, html, forms, http-post, spark-java

I want to be able to post a form that has indexed array fields, and read those fields from Sparkjava.  Based on some reading around, I've found a handful of recommendations to use square brackets to index my repeated fields.  This looks like a php convention that automatically parses the repeated field into an array.  However I can't figure out what magic Sparkjava is doing to this field, it seems to ignore the brackets and presents me with a null object for that key.

Since that was clear as mud, here is some code:

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
  Array: <input type="text" name="MyArray[1]" /><br>
  Array: <input type="text" name="MyArray[2]" /><br>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is my form handling endpoint:

```
post("/form", (req, res) -> {
    String data = req.queryMap().toMap().toString();
    return data;
});
```

When I enter values into my form and submit, the resulting page displays:

```
{name=[Ljava.lang.String;@7ae881bf, MyArray=null}
```

So it parses `name` as a key (just like any boring form) but looks like it parses the trailing `[]` on the MyArray field as a signifier of some special structure that should be parsed into a specific object.  It behaves the same if I leave out the indexes, and name both fields `MyArray[]`.  I would be happy if it let me access the keys as `MyArray[1]` and `MyArray[2]`, but I would prefer to understand what sort of parsing magic Sparkjava is trying to do so I can leverage it.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think spark will resolve it. Maybe you can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158475/parse-post-body-to-java-object-using-spark